# How do you measure proximity between variables and a outcome (numeric)

Tags: r, math, statistics, distance, proximity

For example.

```
series1--> 10 31 53 70 90
series2-->  20 40 30 40 70 
series3
   .
   .

True answer 1 3 5 7 9
```

I want to rank this series and pick up one series which most match the TRUE ANSWER by statistic method. "Match" mean their proportion of each values is close to True Answer.

Comment: you might want to look into the ```dist``` function

Comment: for me this is just the definition of the pearson correlation coefficient (cor(..)).. no? is that what you want?

Comment: if series4 -->10 31 0 70 90, there are many zero inside my dataset. it will get smaller pearson correlation coefficient than other?

Comment: sure it will! you mean you want to exclude the zero values from the calculation?

Comment: @user2645553 Hi, if any answer solves your problem can you click on "accept it" so that other people can see it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

hope i'm not too naive but so if you talking about the pearson correlation this will sort your series in decreasing order of correlation with the true series

```
df<-data.frame(a=c(10,31,53,70,90), b=c(20,40,30,40,70), c=c(1,3,5,7,8))
true=c(1,3,5,7,9)
res<-data.frame('cor'=cor(df,true))
res[order(-res$cor), , drop=FALSE]
```